# javascript set default form behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a website which is very form intensive. I use the following plugins:

```
jquery.form  
jquery.validate
```

Forms are loaded dynamically as well (via ajax).
Almost all my forms are submitted via ajax, using the jquery.form `ajaxForm()`, or `ajaxSubmit()` - when used in the `submitHandler` of the validation plugin.
So basically each time I load a form to my page, I need to set up the validate() plugin, ajaxForm..  And now I would also want to write some code to prevent double submits (i.e, disable the submit button after submit, until a response is fetched).  All of these seems too boilerplate, as now to prevent double submit, I need to go over each form in my site (and as I've said, there are many).

I would like to somehow bind these as a default behavior using delegated events.
So the question: Is it possible to .preventDefault() on **delegated** submit event? example:

```
$(document).on("submit", ".my-form", function(event) { 
  event.preventDefault(); // works?
  // and now I can ajax submit if the form is valid ?
  // and disable the submit button? or apply any settings to all my forms?
});
```

It somewhat feels hacky for me, since I'm not sure if this actually disables the submit in cross browser way. I mean, does the browser actually **wait** with the form submission until the submit event bubbles all the way up in the DOM tree?

Comment: no problem delegating `event.preventDefault()`. Other than that not really clear what other specific issues you have. See [ask] and try to narrow this down to be more specific question(s)

Comment: jQuery.validate is not an event binding, so you can't use delegation for it. You have to call it explicitly on each form that requires validation. Also, the options usually need to be tailored to each form -- the `rules` and `messages` options need to list all the fields that need to be validated.

Comment: I do know that for each form I set a different rules. That's ok for me. I just said that I use this plugin to tell that I call ajaxSubmit in the handler of validate. The event delegation refer to the ajax submit and the "prevent double submit" script.

Comment: So, my actual question is at the last paragraph, the first part of the question is my "setup" (scripts that I use) + description of the problem I want to solve.